# How do you get the Apps Link Assistant to print to Logcat in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

How do you get the Apps Link Assistant to print to Logcat? Whenever I include a Log.d in the activity, and then test the link with `Test App Links` Logcat remains blank.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to trigger Logcat by typing the following commands into the terminal. However, this has to be done each time I test the URL on the emulator.

`adb kill-server 
adb start-server`

I found the answer in [forums.xmarin](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2274/message-couldnt-connect-to-logcat-getprocessid-returned-0)